# Swift 3 converting NSClassFromString wants a "," seperator

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I am trying to convert the following obj-c code into swift 3:

```
UIView *targetView = nil;
for (UIView *subView in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews) {
    if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationButton")]) {
        for (UILabel *label in subView.subviews) {
            if ([label isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                if ([label.text isEqualToString:"right"]) {
                    targetView = subView;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

CGRect rect = [targetView convertRect:targetView.frame toView:self.view];
CGPoint center_you_need = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
```

So far I have this:

```
var targetView: UIView? = nil
        for subView: UIView in self.navigationController!.navigationBar.subviews {
            if (subView is NSClassFromString("UINavigationButton")) {
                for label: UILabel in subView.subviews {
                    if (label is UILabel) {
                        if (label.text! == "right") {
                            targetView = subView
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var rect = targetView!.convertRect(targetView!.frame, to: self.view)
        var center_you_need = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
```

But this gives me the errors:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var targetView: UIView? = nil
for subView in self.navigationController!.navigationBar.subviews {
    if let navButtonClass = NSClassFromString("UINavigationButton") {
        if subView.isKind(of: navButtonClass) {
            for view in subView.subviews {
                if let label = view as? UILabel {
                    if (label.text! == "right") {
                        targetView = subView
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
var rect = targetView!.convert(targetView!.frame, to: self.view)
var center_you_need = CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY)
```

However you should avoid such code whenever possible.
You can save UIBarButtonItem as a property of your controller and then:

1. If it's a custom bar button item, use it's customView property
2. If customView is nil you can try to access the view with `valueForKey` method:

```
let targetView = barButtonItem.customView ?? barButtonItem.value(forKey:"view")
```

Comment: Is there any other way to get the UIBarButtonItem center position?

Comment: Have a look at the updated answer. Not sure if it works now, but it should :)